# Make product buyable only once

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello guys i trying to make product can be buyable only once so i make that

`productsTable: id,name,desc,price,onlyOnce(Boolean 0-1)`

And i make pivot table too: `orders: user_id,product_id`

I try this code:

```
public function showProducts(Category $category, User $user) {

    $products = $category->products()->where('onlyOnce', 1)->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $userOrders = $user->orders()->pluck('user_Id')->toArray();
    $missProducts = array_intersect($userOrders, $products);


    $extras = $category->products()->whereNotIn('id', $missProducts)->get();


    return view('products.category',compact('extras'));
}
```

But not work, some ideas how to do that?

(If you need here is my models)
**Product.php**

```
 class Product extends Model
 {
  protected $fillable = [];

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function categories() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

}

**Order.php**

```
class Order extends Model
{
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getTotalPrice() {

    $orders = self::with('product')->get();
    $total = $orders->pluck('product')->sum('price');

    return $total;
}
```

}

**User.php**
class User extends Authenticatable
{

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name'];

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

}

With that code it return empty array i don't know why, so please if you have some ideas how i can fix that or what new code to type answear! Thanks in advice, peace! ;)

Comment: You're intersecting the user id with the product id? Can you explain what you're controller code is meant to be doing i.e. is it to get the only once products that a user has bought or just exclude products that are only once etc?

Comment: I want to show products that user is not purchased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up your database kind of weird, I would have done it differently, however the following code should retrieve all the products not purchased by a user. Let me know if it works.

```
$productID = 123;
$userID = 10;
$purchased = $orders->select('product_id')->where('user_id', $userID)->toArray();

$notPurchased = $productsTable->whereNotIn('id',$purchased)->get();
```

You could then pass $notPurchased to a view, and loop over it with a foreach() loop to get each unpurchased product id.